# Mask arbitrarily sized UIImageView with resizable UIImage mask

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, calayer

Current code:

```
    self.backgroundImageView.image = [self.message imageOfSize:self.message.size]; // Random image, random size

    UIImage *rightBubbleBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"BubbleRight"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:BubbleRightCapInsets
    resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

    CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
    mask.contents = (id)[rightBubbleBackground CGImage];

    mask.frame = self.backgroundImageView.layer.frame;
    self.backgroundImageView.layer.mask = mask;
    self.backgroundImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

This does not work properly. Though the mask is applied, the `rightBubbleBackground` does not resize correctly to fit `self.backgroundImageView`, even though it has resizing cap insets (`BubbleRightCapInsets`) set.

Original Image:

[image: Original image]

Mask image (`rightBubbleBackground`):

[image: Mask]

Result:

[image: Result]

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928188/1593651) but it only works for symmetrical images. Maybe I could modify that answer for my use.

Comment: I think `mask.frame = self.backgroundImageView.layer.frame;` should be `mask.frame = self.backgroundImageView.layer.bounds;`. Using your code will result in a shift of the mask if the layer's frame is not equal to bounds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was wrong. That answer can be modified to work for asymmetrical images. I worked on [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11928188/1593651) a bit and solved my own problem.

The following code made my cap insets work for the mask layer:

```
mask.contentsCenter =
CGRectMake(BubbleRightCapInsets.left/rightBubbleBackground.size.width,
BubbleRightCapInsets.top/rightBubbleBackground.size.height,
1.0/rightBubbleBackground.size.width,
1.0/rightBubbleBackground.size.height);
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: what is the value of BubbleRightCapInsets .. i use this   UIEdgeInsets BubbleRightCapInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15.0f,20.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f);

Comment: @MANCHIKANTIKRISHNAKISHORE I have since redesigned the app and no longer remember the insets. You should use a greater value for `right` though, to account for the arrow, and perhaps `bottom` too.

Comment: Just add that for retina support `mask.contentsScale = rightBubbleBackground.scale`

Comment: hmm... what contentsGravity have you used ? How do you resize the layer to the size of the penguin image ? Can you show us the whole set of codes around contents ? Lastly what if the image is smaller than the bubble ? what happens then?

Comment: @ironclap This was too long ago, so I do not remember much of the details. But I believe `contentsGravity` was left default. And if the image was smaller than the bubble, the image stretched to fill the bubble's size.

Comment: @duci9y thanks... I ended up using bezierpath to redo bubble. Easier to engineer than to draw those bubbles using illustrator :-). Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I had (part of) the same problem - i.e. the pixelated layer contents. For me it was solved by setting the contentsScale value on the CALayer - for some reason the default scale on CALayers is always 1.0, even on Retina devices.

i.e.

```
layer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Also, if you're drawing a shape using CAShapeLayer and wondering its edges look a little jagged on retina devices, try:

```
shapeLayer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
shapeLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```